# How to load a model trained on google colab

Tags: tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory

am following this [tutorial](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1VuPv_SInihZIO9gwy1p0YqYQy76bwBuS) to try using google's BERT for text classification, after training the model I saved using

```
# serialize model to JSON
model_json = model.to_json()
with open("model.json", "w") as json_file:
    json_file.write(model_json)
# serialize weights to HDF5
model.save_weights("model.h5")
print("Saved model to disk")
```

I downloaded the models and am trying to load them as below

```
json_file = open(os.path.join(self.root, 'model.json'), 'r')
        loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
        json_file.close()

        cs = get_custom_objects()
        cs['GlorotNormal'] = tf.keras.initializers.glorot_normal()
        cs['GlorotUniform'] = tf.keras.initializers.glorot_uniform()

        model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json, custom_objects=cs)
        print('loaded model json')
        # load weights into new model
        model.load_weights(os.path.join(self.root, 'model.h5'))
```

if I removed 'ragged' from the model, the function `mdoel_from_json` hangs
and `tf.keras.models.model_from_json` throws `ValueError: Unknown initializer: GlorotNormal`
what the correct way to load the model ?

Comment: Why not just `model.save("model.h5")` and use `keras.models.load_model`?

Comment: I remeber I tried that long time ago and had different issues and recommendation was to save model and weights separately

Answer (score 0):

I had to add `os.environ['TF_KERAS'] = '1'` before importing `tensorflow`